# How can add polls in magento page

Tags: php, magento

How can i add polls into a page in `MAGENTO`?

> i am try to using this

```
 <div class="left_pan">
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sidebar') ?>
</div>
```

but not working 
anybody help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tutorial [Magento poll wiki tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-configure-and-use-polls)

Also check "poll.xml" in your themes layout file.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to edit app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/poll.xml**

```
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll">
            <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
            <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Change referance name as per your requirement.
Hope this helps..